# Save InlineShape picture to file in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to extract a picture from a Word document and save it in a file, using vba.
I don't really care about the output format, as long as it is readable.

The picture is in line with text and is therefore an `InlineShape` in vba.

I have tried something using the *ActiveX Data Object Library (ADODB)*, see code below.

##### Code

```
Dim oInlineShape As InlineShape, _
ImageStream

Set oInlineShape = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)

Set ImageStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With ImageStream
    .Type = 1
    .Open
    .Write oInlineShape.Range.EnhMetaFileBits
    .savetofile ActiveDocument.Path & "\image.bmp"
    .Close
End With
Set ImageStream = Nothing
```

There is no need to include the reference to the "ActiveX Data Object Library".
I have not specified `ImageStream`'s type to avoid having to do so.

##### Result

I cannot read the `image.bmp` file using the Windows Photos App, but I can insert it back into the Word document or convert the file to a jpg (I used ImageMagick but I don't think it matters).

| Original | Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCSok.jpg] | [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QInGc.jpg] |

- The result image has weird white borders. I don't know where they are coming from.
  I tried to understand by adding `oInlineShape.Select` in my code, only the image is selected...
- Its quality is very poor compared to the original image (this may not be visible in the uploaded pictures).
  I believe this is because I resized the image in Word.

#### Other possible method

I read in old forum threads that the vba code can call functions from the Windows API and therefore can paste the clipboard contents to a file.

I know how to put a Shape or InlineShape in the Word clipboard. However, I do not know how to connect to the Windows API using vba and what function from it to use.

Many many thanks!!

Comment: That code can include paragraph marks after the inline image. I see a little extra white space after the images, but the image quality isn't too bad. Other alternate approaches include saving the Word doc as HTML, then retrieving the image, or unzipping the Word file and getting the image from the word\media folder. You could also invoke an instance of PowerPoint, paste the image and export it. PowerPoint is much better then Word with graphics.

Comment: It does seem to be the white space arount the picture in the document, but I can't get rid of it...
The HTML solution does not work for me because I cannot get  specific image from the document, only all images.
I will try with PowerPoint, I had not thought about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for 20 years but never found answer, until discovering WordXML.

You can test by calling: saveImage Selection.InlineShapes(1), "C:\tmp\test.png"
Make sure there is a "tmp" directory on the C drive.

```
Private Sub saveImage(shp As InlineShape, path As String)

    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = shp.Range.Duplicate
    r.start = r.start - 1
    r.End = r.End + 1
    
    ''shp.range.WordOpenXML does not always contain the binary data
    ''s = shp.Range.WordOpenXML
    
    s = r.WordOpenXML
    
    i = InStr(s, "<pkg:binaryData>") + 16
    
    If i = 16 Then
        MsgBox "No binary data found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    j = InStr(i, s, "</pkg:binaryData>")
    
    s = Mid$(s, i, j - i)
    
    
    Dim DecodeBase64() As Byte
    Dim objXML As Object 'MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As Object 'MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    'create node with type of base 64 and decode
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = s
    DecodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

    Open path For Binary As #1
       Put #1, 1, DecodeBase64
    Close #1

End Sub
```