# Save InlineShape picture to file in Word VBA using WordXML

Tags: vba, ms-word

Reviewing this question [Save InlineShape picture to file in Word VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68301492), the accepted answer works fine for our case but the saved png doesn't have the size used in the document and simply has the full original size.

As in the original question, the alternative that uses ADODB generates some artifacts in the file (white spaces) that I couldn't fix in code (don't know what causes them).

The HTML or the zip ways don't work for me because I have to keep track of each picture's name and location in the document (not that is important for this question but is a constrain of the process, I save those names in a CSV that also relates to the table in which appears the picture).

The way I used to do it was to copy the inlineshape range as a picture and save the clipboard content to a file with a powershell command run from within the vba code, but the antivirus where flagging the code and didn't let it to go through (I can't touch the antivirus, as is a macro for the client to execute)

I have searched but can't find a way to save in a folder the picture (inline shapes) with the size used in the document.

The saved picture could be in png, jpg or bmp.

Edit: I believe that the trick is in how the range is created from the Inline Shape's Range

```vb
 Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = shp.Range.Duplicate
    r.Start = r.Start - 1
    r.End = r.End + 1
```

I don't know if it is possible that when the creation of the duplicated range it could respect the configuration of the original object

Comment: You really need to say a bit more about constraints (e.g. do you need to save in a particular format, or not), what  you've tried - a quick search reveals a number of different approaches - and what goes wrong. E.g. one approach saves to HTML then looks through the supporting files folder for images; another copies to PowerPoint, then saves via features in its object model that Word does not have.

Comment: @jonsson - the question is already clear - size is the constraint. The OP wants "a way to save in a folder the picture (inline shapes) with the size used in the document"

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt The OP talks about a "saved png" but it wasn't clear for example whether the solution had to save images specifically in .png format (with size info). If the OP has looked at the HTML export method and rejected it, saying why might help pin down the requirement.

Comment: @jonsson I have updated the question, hope it clarifies a little further the situation

Comment: @Andres Useful update, thanks. I wondered whether it might be necessary to save the picture using one of the techniques you have already looked at, then get picture dimension info. separately and modify the png/jpg/whatever. Don't know how to do that but will have a look when I can.

Comment: There are 2 sizes in play. The first is the size set in the bitmap. As one example, a JPG file will have a header that has the total image size in pixels, plus a JFIF section that will include the pixel density or pixels per inch setting. Then Word has a second size, that reflects the resizing of the image that the user has done. The WordOpenXml command saves the picture with its original header information. To do what you want to do, you would have to change the header information as you write the image, changing the JFIF information to a different pixel density to reflect alteration in Word.