# VBA : Manipulate selected Picture with external script

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I have a dotx/docx document with many pictures and need to manipulate many of them in the same way. Therefore I have written a Python script which will perform the image manipulation on a jpg file.

All I need to do now is to write a VBA script which will save the currently selected picture as jpg file, call the Python script and replace the picture in the document. And then assign this macro to a keyboard shortcut.

My VBA code is currently:

```vb
Sub ManipulateImage()
    Dim sel As Word.Selection
    Dim shp As InlineShape

    Set sel = Selection
    If sel.Type = wdSelectionInlineShape Then
        Set shp = sel.InlineShapes(1)
        Debug.Print "**"
        'Save as picture
    End If
    
    'Manipulate saved picture
    Shell "mypythonscript.py imgfile"
    
    'Replace picture
    'sel.PasteSpecial?

End Sub
```

I currently can't figure out how to save the InlineShape object as jpg image using VBA. If I do it manually, I can simply right click the picture and select "Save as Picture".

Comment: For the moment, I'm saving a copy of the document as html file. This way all the pictures will be exported at once. Then I can run my script to manipulate the images. Afterwards I have to manually change every picture (right click, "Change Picture")

Comment: When you're inserting a photo into Word, change the _Insert_ button of the dialog to _Link to File_. Then all photos will be saved as external files instead of embedded in Word. You can run your script on those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for saving inline shapes in Word VBA:

```
Private Sub saveImage(shp As InlineShape, path As String)

    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = shp.Range.Duplicate
    r.start = r.start - 1
    r.End = r.End + 1
    
    ''shp.range.WordOpenXML does not always contain the binary data
    ''s = shp.Range.WordOpenXML
    
    s = r.WordOpenXML
    
    i = InStr(s, "<pkg:binaryData>") + 16
    
    If i = 16 Then
        MsgBox "No binary data found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    j = InStr(i, s, "</pkg:binaryData>")
    
    s = Mid$(s, i, j - i)
    
    
    Dim DecodeBase64() As Byte
    Dim objXML As Object 'MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As Object 'MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    'create node with type of base 64 and decode
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = s
    DecodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

    Open path For Binary As #1
       Put #1, 1, DecodeBase64
    Close #1

End Sub
```

See [Save InlineShape picture to file in Word VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301492/save-inlineshape-picture-to-file-in-word-vba) for more information.