How To LoadPicture from InLineShape Instead of File Using MS Word 365 VBA
I need to view in a UserForm each .InLineShape picture (with its respective .AlternativeText) placed inside a Word document. I need to do this check inside a UserForm, picture by picture.
so, I created a UserForm with an image and a label object, along with the navigation buttons.
the following code allows me to load this picture from a file:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    caminhoArquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Image Files(*.jpg), *.jpg")
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(caminhoArquivo)
End Sub

I'd like to load this picture from an .InLineShape, instead of a file picture.
I'd appreciate your help.
thanks in advance.

Please check out STEPHEN BULLEN's solution, PastePicture.zip, available at this link. If you are running the code in a 64-bit environment, you may need to revise the API.

@taller the solution is suitable for charts but, it can't handle wordart or shapes. even so, the code doesn't work in my 64-bit system.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301492/save-inlineshape-picture-to-file-in-word-vba

@AlexBoorjs You can copy shape to clipboard with ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Select : Selection.Copy and then use STEPHEN's code. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you need to adapt the API for 64-bit.

@taller you are right. copy to clipboard is the way. thanks a lot!
